# Реализация и соблюдение общего поведения ABI на С++ в UNIX системах

Tags: c++, dll, library

Недавно начал писать свою библиотеку логирования для дальнейшего его использования в будущих проектах на языке `С++`. Сама библиотека уже готова, но вот проблема! Оказывается, при написании библиотек, требуется соблюдать общее поведение [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Я этого не знал! Начал читать про саму концепцию `ABI`, и в принципе, я понял, что от меня требуется. Но вот незадача! В `C++` **ABI** описываются подробности на двоичном уровне, которые не специфицируются в Стандарте. Стандарт описывает общее поведение, но не говорит как оно должно быть реализовано. При попытке найти что то сносное, в котором будут показаны примеры соблюдения `ABI`, я ничего не нашел. Есть ли наглядные примеры, в которых подробно показывают, как правильно реализовать поведение `ABI`?

Вот примеры, которые я так понимаю, являются частью реализации `ABI`:

```
// Использование поддержки динамической видимости символов ELF C++

#define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden" )))

// ...

class DLL_LOCAL Sink
{
public:
 
    Sink(void) noexcept;
    Sink &operator=(const Sink &) noexcept = default;
    Sink &operator=(Sink &&)      noexcept = default;
    Sink(const Sink &)            noexcept = default;
    Sink(Sink &&)                 noexcept = default;
    virtual ~Sink(void)           noexcept = default;

    // ...
    
    virtual void print(const std::string &message) noexcept;
};

class DLL_PUBLIC StdoutSink : public Sink
{
public:

    StdoutSink(void) noexcept;
    StdoutSink &operator=(const StdoutSink &) noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink &operator=(StdoutSink &&)      noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink(const StdoutSink &)            noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink(StdoutSink &&)                 noexcept = default;
   ~StdoutSink(void) noexcept                 override = default;

    // ...

    void print(const std::string &message) noexcept override;
};
```

А так же, и такой пример:

```
class StdoutSinkImpl
{
public:

    StdoutSinkImpl(void) noexcept;
    StdoutSinkImpl &operator=(const StdoutSinkImpl &) noexcept = default;
    StdoutSinkImpl &operator=(StdoutSinkImpl &&)      noexcept = default;
    StdoutSinkImpl(const StdoutSinkImpl &)            noexcept = default;
    StdoutSinkImpl(StdoutSinkImpl &&)                 noexcept = default;
   ~StdoutSinkImpl(void)                              noexcept = default;

    // ...

    void print(const std::string &message) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << message << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
};

class StdoutSink
{
public:

    StdoutSink(void) noexcept : p_stdoutSinkImpl(new StdoutSinkImpl)
    {
        
    }
    
    StdoutSink &operator=(const StdoutSink &) noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink &operator=(StdoutSink &&)      noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink(const StdoutSink &)            noexcept = default;
    StdoutSink(StdoutSink &&)                 noexcept = default;
   ~StdoutSink(void) noexcept
    {
        if (!p_stdoutSinkImpl) {
            delete p_stdoutSinkImpl;
        }
    }

    // ...

    void print(const std::string &message) noexcept
    {
        p_stdoutSinkImpl->print(message);
    }

private:

    StdoutSinkImpl *p_stdoutSinkImpl = nullptr;
};
```

Во втором случае, мы скрываем класс реализации, от класса, которым будем пользоваться, для того, чтобы если при модификации полей класса `StdoutSinkImpl`, класс `StdoutSink` был бы неизменен, и не подтвергался перекомпиляции, так как приватный объект его всегда равен размеру указателя. Данный способ, я так полагаю, примерно реализует поведение `ABI`, но все же, не уверен. Но на счет первого примера, у меня нет идей, как правильно его использовать. Если у Вас есть идеи и конкретные примеры реализации `ABI`, я буду Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: ABI реализуется в компиляторах, а то, что приведено в этом примере - это API.

Comment: сколько интересного кода, а утечка памяти на ровном месте в классе StdoutSink. В целом, хотите хорошего кода - не заставляйте с++ классы торчать с библиотеки.

Comment: `if (p_stdoutSinkImpl) { delete p_stdoutSinkImpl;  }` - серьезно? можно просто delete

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо большое за Вам комментарий. На счет того, что ABI реализуется в компиляторах, я согласен. Но все же, при прочтении общих правил соблюдения ABI, и со стороны программиста так же должны быть предприняты меры, чтобы реализовать абстракцию ABI, и что бы сама концепция ABI "не сломалась"  при малейших изменениях в библиотеке.

Comment: @KoVadim Написал так, ибо это просто абстракция самого класса.

Comment: @KoVadim А на счет Вашего комментария, Вы бы могли немного поподробнее объяснить, что вы имели ввиду, под высказыванием - "не заставляйте с++ классы торчать с библиотеки".

Comment: соблюдение ABI со стороны программиста заключается в том, чтобы не линковать вместе единицы трансляции, собранные с использованием разных ABI. ABI зависит исключительно от используемого компилятора и настроек сборки, а не от кода библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснения. Лишь одно не понятно. Почему, то, что показано во втором примере, считают некой реализацией ABI. Говорю это так, ибо и сам ментор, ссылался на такой пример.  Какие плюсы данного примера, так как я вижу один лишь большой минус - дополнительный код.

Comment: @WithoutExperience, прикладной код никак не может реализовывать ABI. Скорее всего, вы не так поняли ментора и путаете ABI с API. Второй пример похож на реализацию т. н. opaque pointer. Загуглите этот термин.

Comment: Преимущества использования opaque pointer в том, что при изменении `StdoutSinkImpl` будет сохранена бинарная совместимость с другими модулями. Наверное, ваш вопрос был об этом. В общем, почитайте про этот opaque pointer.

Comment: @eanmos тут не opaque pointer, а pimpl с указателем на абстрактный класс. "при изменении StdoutSinkImpl будет сохранена бинарная совместимость с другими модулями." - это еще бабушка на двое сказала

Comment: @user7860670, pimpl это и есть opaque pointer (или паттерн мост, или d-pointer). А про бабушку не понял.

Comment: @WithoutExperience, вот здесь популярно написано о проблемах с бинарной совместимостью: https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B#Definition.

Comment: @eanmos @user7860670 Спасибо большое за помощь, особенно за `pimpl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас нет необходимости реализовывать ABI, особенно, если это не системная библиотека. Его реализовали за вас в компиляторах. Действительные и простые изменения в ABI Вы можете вносить меняя декларацию вызова функций, идущих на экспорт, но, опять же, бинарный интерфейс, в конечном счете, за компилятором.

Если интересно больше почитать про ABI в UNIX, то вот
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

И в UNIX нет dll, есть so :)